# Routing between docker desktop and docker desktop kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

Let's suppose I have (all in docker desktop, Windows 10)

1. A docker container running a service (e.g. redis)
2. A container running in a pod into kubernetes (kubernetes provided by docker desktop), with corresponding kubernetes service.

What urls should I use to make the two containers see each other?

Comment: The easiest thing will be to move the Redis cache into Kubernetes as well.  This will also be easier to translate into other environments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888113/docker-kubernetes-and-name-reslution?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The network will become more straightforward if you run everything as docker or everything as K8s. Kubernetes has its own networking implementation. Redis and your app are pretty much on different networks.  You'll need to know how to egress.  You may expose redis on the host and then have your K8s talk to your host on that port.The host network is probably visible to both of them.

How will this look in production?  Is Redis going to be a PaaS or SaaS cloud service?  Is Redis going to be deployed in K8s?  Docker in prod seems unlikely these days.